# Extracting value from a string using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My example string is as follows:

```
"firstName":"Alice", "dealersCode":850503,"productCode":"99110X0"
```

I want to extract `850503` from `dealersCode`. For that, I tried the following regex with sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*dealersCode:\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

The above command prints nothing so I believe that I'm doing something wrong. I created the following regex on https://regex101.com/:

```
(?:\"dealersCode|\')(?<key>[^"]*)(?:\"|\')(?=:)(?:\:\s*)(?:\"|\')?(?<value>true|false|[0-9a-zA-Z\+\-\.\$]*)
```

It didn't work with bash.

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may use: `sed 's/^.*"dealersCode":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`

Comment: Or `grep -oP '"dealersCode":\K[0-9]+'`.

Comment: Is that fragment part of a string holding some JSON data? If so, use jq, not sed.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks so much for that, worked flawlessly

Comment: @PesaThe, this grep didn't work. Looks like something is wrong on the syntax

Comment: @Shawn It's a json inside a bigger string with other informations so I would have to remove the json inside the string to jq it. I thought it was more difficult

Comment: @BernardoMorais `-P` option might not be implemented in your version of `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), I solve my problem with:

```
sed 's/^.*"dealersCode":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string to be found:

- certainly exists in the string,
- and is the first block of numbers

*GNU* `grep` works:

```
grep -wo '[0-9]*' <<< \
   '"firstName":"Alice", "dealersCode":850503,"productCode":"99110X0"'
```

If the string might not be there, this is better:

```
grep 'dealersCode[^,]*,' | grep -wo '[0-9]*' <<< \
   '"firstName":"Alice", "dealersCode":850503,"productCode":"99110X0"'
```